# How to use PostgisFunctions in hibernate-spatial to transform CRS geometry

Tags: hibernate-spatial, grails-4

- Hibernate (entity-manager, spatial...) version is 5.4.14
- Database dialect as follows: `org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisPG95Dialect`
- PostgresSQL 10, Postgis 2.4

Geometry field is being defined by `org.locationtech.jts.geom` thus in regards to spatial methods the one can implement following: [covers, within, buffer, contains...(see Concrete Methods)](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/Geometry.html). 
 
`org.locationtech.jts.geom`doesn't provide a method for transforming CRS, however hibernate-spatial does([see hibernate-spatial dialect function support](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#spatial-configuration-dialect)).

How do we call Postgis function e.g `transform` over hibernate-spatial?
 
As was stated in the comment of the `PostgisPG95Dialect` class:
`Extends the {@code PostgreSQL95Dialect} to add support for the Postgis spatial types, functions and operators`, however calling function either with `PostgisPG95Dialect`, `PostgisFunctions` or directly over `geometry` it's not found.

```
PostgreSQL95Dialect.transform(geometry,4326)
SpatialFunction.transform(geometry,4326)
PostgisFunctions.transform(geometry,4326)
geometry.transform(4326)
```

In case, when the geometry has to be mapped with `org.hibernate.spatial.GeolatteGeometryType` ([see hibernate-spatial types](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#spatial-types)) comes the following error( error with `org.hibernate.spatial.JTSGeometryType` is identical):

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate Type: org.hibernate.spatial.GeolatteGeometryType
at org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory.type(TypeFactory.java:113)
at org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory.byClass(TypeFactory.java:70)
at org.hibernate.type.TypeResolver.heuristicType(TypeResolver.java:126)
at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:473)
at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:455)
at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:227)
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:624)
at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:267)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:351)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:464)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingContextConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(HibernateMappingContextConfiguration.java:287)
at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.HibernateConnectionSourceFactory.create(HibernateConnectionSourceFactory.java:86)
at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.java:39)
at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.java:23)
at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.java:64)
at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.java:52)
at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.ConnectionSourcesInitializer.create(ConnectionSourcesInitializer.groovy:24)
at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore.<init>(HibernateDatastore.java:212)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor83.newInstance(Unknown Source)
atjava.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:172)
... 127 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.hibernate.spatial.GeolatteGeometryType
at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:571)
at org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory.type(TypeFactory.java:105)
... 149 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.hibernate.spatial.GeolatteGeometryType.<init>()
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3350)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:556)
... 150 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been found out workaround solution direcly over hibernate sql.
Hibernate-Spatial PostGIS e.g `transform` function can be called using Hibernate SQL syntax query over a Domain Class and its geometry field in `Grails` as following example:

```
Geometry geometry4326 =  Parcel.executeQuery("select transform(geometry,4326) as geom from Parcel where id=1").first()
```

Geometry field retains `locationtech.jts` definition.

Comment: The `transform` function is registered by the `Posgis95SpatialDialect` (and some others) for use in HQL or JPA queries. So your solution is not a workaround, it is the proper way to use the function